# Select All implementation on Radio button in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to make a set of radio groups like Image(Pls refer attached image link) , But not able to set up the Select All functionality completely.

Image link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBOhe.png

Select all should be checked/Unchecled based on below conditions:
1)checked If All items beneath are checked and none is disabled otherwise Unchecked.

Below Is the code for HTML and TS File:

HTML:

```
   <div class="row table-group collapse show" >
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="table-responsive custom-table">
            <table class="table manage-role">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col"></th>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <div class="radio-box">
                      <div class="custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" class="right-gap" name=123 [checked]="checkForSelectAllRadioValue1('none')" (change)="allCheck1($event,'none')">
                        <label class="" for="selectAll">Select All</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <div class="radio-box">
                      <div class="custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" class="right-gap" name=123 [checked]="checkForSelectAllRadioValue1('read')" (change)="allCheck1($event,'read')">
                        <label class="" for="readAll">Select All</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <th scope="col">
                    <div class="radio-box">
                      <div class="custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" class="right-gap" name=123 [checked]="checkForSelectAllRadioValue1('edit')" (change)="allCheck1($event,'edit')">
                        <label class="" for="editAll">Select All</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

                <tr *ngFor="let option of testData">
                  <th>{{option.Name}}</th>
                  <td *ngFor="let item of  option.access">
                    <div class="radio-box">
                      <div class="custom-radio">
                        <input type="radio" class="right-gap" name={{option.id}} [checked]=item.value (change)="handleRadioClick1(item,option)" [disabled]="!item.enabled">
                        <label>{{item.accessType}}</label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>


              </tbody>

            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

 - Component.ts:

 this.testData = [
{ "Name": "One", "id": 1, "access": [{ accessType: 'none', enabled: true, value: 1 }, { accessType: 'read', enabled: true, value: 0 }, { accessType: 'edit', enabled: true, value: 0 }] },
{ "Name": "Two", "id": 2, "access": [{ accessType: 'none', enabled: true, value: 1 }, { accessType: 'read', enabled: true, value: 0 }, { accessType: 'edit', enabled: true, value: 0 }] },
{ "Name": "Three", "id": 3, "access": [{ accessType: 'none', enabled: false, value: 0 }, { accessType: 'read', enabled: true, value: 1 }, { accessType: 'edit', enabled: true, value: 0 }] }]


    checkForSelectAllRadioValue1(accessType: string) {
          let allAreChecked: boolean = true;
        this.testData.forEach(x => {
          let matchingLine = x.access.find(y => y.accessType.toLowerCase() == accessType.toLowerCase());
          if (matchingLine.value != 1 || !matchingLine.enabled) { allAreChecked = false; }
          })
          // return (!allAreChecked || anyOneDisabled) ? 0 : 1;
        return (allAreChecked) ? 1 : 0;

        }

      allCheck1(e, accesstype) {
        this.testData.forEach(x => {
          if (x.access && x.access.length > 0) {
            if (x.access.find(z => z.accessType.toLowerCase() == accesstype.toLowerCase()).enabled) {
                x.access.forEach(y => {
                  y.value = (y.accessType.toLowerCase() == accesstype.toLowerCase() && y.enabled) ? 1 : 0;
                })
              }
            }
          })

      }

      handleRadioClick1(me, parent) {
        parent.access.filter(x => x.accessType != me.accessType).forEach(y => y.value=0);
        if (me.value == 0) { me.value = 1 }
        else if (me.value == 1) { me.value = 0 }
      }
```

Any help appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: Radio buttons are by definition single value selection. What you want is a checkbox group styled to look like circles.

Comment: Yes,I want that Radio should act like a checkbox . Once Checked , It should check all radios of the vertical group

Comment: You have it backwards. You want to use checkboxes that act like radios. You can’t force a radio input to act like a checkbox, but you can use js to force a checkbox to act like a radio.